# How to concatenate 1 textbox values into url

Tags: livecode

```
  local custid 
  put the text of field "txtcustid" into custid

  put the URL"http://htp2.hitecpoint.in:98/api/live/"+custid  into tPreferencesFile
```

Hello Friends i am facing a problem of livecode.I want to combine textbox value into a url.
I put value of textbox in  a variable. I got a error "button "Button": execution error at line 32 (Operators +: error in left operand), char 15".Please help.

Comment: URL is not a property. It is a keyword, purists might call it a function. Please, don't write "the" in front of "URL", even if it works. You might get in trouble when updating your version of LiveCode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try

```
local custid 
put the text of field "txtcustid" into custid

put URL("http://htp2.hitecpoint.in:98/api/live/" & custid)  into tPreferencesFile
```

(LiveCode use '&' to join values together instead of '+')